# Email migration from Mac Mail to Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: mail.app, email, migration

I think this topic must have been posted earlier also.

I want to transfer my emails from mac mail to outlook 2011. When I go to import option in outlook 2011 and select the mac mail to import the mail boxes, all I get imported is blank folders every time.

The results were the same even after reinstalling office 2011.

Can anyone share their views on this topic and I would be very greatful if anyone could provide me solution of this question on how to migrate the emails from Mac Mail to Outlook 2011.

Answer (score 0):

For transferring all your apple mail items in to Outlook 2011, there is a need of robust data format conversion process. This step helps you to migrate from one mail client to another. In this reference, an apple mail to Outlook 2011 converter is desired to fulfill to requirement. However, you can accomplish this task by manual method also but it faces some pitfalls.

So, check a review of required converter that i found as a resource on web mentioned below:
http://download.cnet.com/Mail-Exporter-Pro/3000-2369_4-75877193.html